# Using page title in Sharepoint 2013 content search webpart query

Tags: sharepoint-designer, page-layout, content-search-web-part

I'm creating a page layout using Sharepoint Designer 2013. I'm adding content search webparts into the page layout and would like to add a page title to the query in the content search web part.

Can this be done? Is it possible with ASPX or do I need Visual Studio?

Update: I tried adding {Page.Title} to QueryTemplate value in the DataProviderJSON attribute of the webpart. But after applying the layout, I get "An unexpected error has occurred.".